# How to bind ⌘← and ⌘→ to previous and next tab in Safari 10?

Tags: keyboard, safari

I'm used to having Command-Left Arrow (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>) and Command-Right Arrow (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>) to switch between tabs, going to the previous and next tabs. I have configured these keys in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts for Safari.app.

However, configuring these shortcuts only works sometimes in Safari 10.1 under macOS 10.12. The behavior is this:

- When pressed in a tab with an active text box, the caret moves to the beginning and end of the row instead
- When pressed in a tab with history forwards or back, Safari goes forward or back in history instead
- *Only* when pressed on a tab that doesn't have the two above conditions, Safari switches to the previous or next tab

How can I disable the two other behaviors or configure the keys correctly so that I can use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> as previous and next tab shortcuts?

Comment: I don't have a Mac in front of me to test and post a full answer, but it appears to have at some point been possible to edit application and/or system-wide key bindings using [System Preferences](https://www.engadget.com/2010/05/29/custom-safari-keyboard-shortcuts-save-my-sanity/) or a program like [KeyBindingsEditor](http://www.cocoabits.com/KeyBindingsEditor/).

Comment: @chrstphrchvz I didn't find any references to the Home/End and history functionality in System Preferences. I also have Home/End already configured similar to what KeyBindingsEditor does. I think the problem is that Safari is not honoring these (for example, Home/End just goes one page up/down instead, same age Page Up/Page Down)

Comment: [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) is another program I would've suggested, but unfortunately it's being [rewritten for Sierra](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md), and I'm not sure if it already can or ever will accommodate the goal here--it might be worth asking them e.g. on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/osx-karabiner)

Comment: I also asked about these secondary/unlisted Safari keyboard shortcuts here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338704/why-can-i-not-set-safari-keyboard-shortcuts-conflicts-with-secondary-unlisted

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Keyboard Maestro**](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to overwrite that ambiguous behavior in Safari and map <kbd>⌘←</kbd>/<kbd>⌘→</kbd> to switch between tabs regardless of any context (text field, history availability), to make it work just like it does in Chrome.
It's a pretty straightforward macro like "**When ⌘← hotkey is pressed, execute “Previous Safari Tab” action**" in a macro folder limited to **Safari**. However, Keyboard Maestro is not free.

Maybe you could also create a free Applescript service to run `Window⟶Show Next Tab` command (since this command ignores context, unlike the respective keyboard shortcut) and change system shortcut <kbd>⌘←</kbd>/<kbd>⌘→</kbd> to run that service instead (would like need to add Safari to Accessibility to allow a script manipulating menu items).