# Apple Developer Forum links broken after WWDC 2020 forum upgrade

Tags: developer-program

At WWDC 2020, Apple updated their Developer Forums.

This has broken links to the old developer forum, such as:   https://developer.apple.com/forums/message/335101

The forum link now says:

> Error - Page Not Found
> The page you’re looking for can’t be found

I [linked that topic on Ask Different here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338704/why-can-i-not-set-safari-keyboard-shortcuts-conflicts-with-secondary-unlisted). The link in that Question is now broken.

---

Were the old Apple Developer Forum topics moved to the new Forum? Was that content deleted?

The URLs were evidently changed. Is there a way to get a new URL if you have only the old URL?

Are the old topics archived anywhere? Or has all that content been deleted?

**Knowing only the old URL, how can I find the migrated topic?**

---

Same discussion on Ask Different Meta, here, for fixing these links SE-wide:
[Apple Developer Forum links broken after WWDC 2020 forum upgrade](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/apple-developer-forum-links-broken-after-wwdc-2020-forum-upgrade)

Comment: So - I think [we as a community need a question like this on meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3924) - so that’s done as well. Let’s focus on helping OP short term - it appears the forums were not scraped / archived by archive.org which was my first instinct to answer this. https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.apple.com/forums/message/335101/*

Answer (score 3):

I logged in to the new Apple Developer Forum.  Under my profile, I still have links to my old topics. They do still exist in the new Forum.

The URLs have changed. They now use `/thread/` rather than `/message/` and the thread/message ID has changed:

```
OLD: https://developer.apple.com/forums/message/335101  
NEW: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/109652
```

<sup>*and the same question posted to Ask Different: [Why can I not set Safari keyboard shortcuts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338704/why-can-i-not-set-safari-keyboard-shortcuts-conflicts-with-secondary-unlisted)*</sup>

That's the details of the change. I don't know if there's a way to link the old and new IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You may not like this answer, but the message ID is not searchable in the new forums alone (or I’m too dense to see how to do that) and I see no signs that Archive.org was allowed to or accomplished mirroring a copy of the content.

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/search/?q=335101